# google places autocomplete ios swift integrate with uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift2, google-places-api, xcode7.1

I am trying to implement google places auto complete api in swift 2.0 project by using the following library:

https://github.com/watsonbox/ios_google_places_autocomplete

the only thing i am not able to figure out is that i want to integrate this with `uitextfield` present in my app form which has country and city fields.

I have implemented this app in a demo project and found out that it also provides me lat long of the location also.

Please help me out by guiding me to integrate this library with the `uitextfield` so when user types in `uitextfield` the results are shown below `uitextfield` only.

By working to implement code in demo app i came to know that the searchbox opens up with the following code:

```
let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocomplete(
        apiKey: "API KEY FROM GOOGLE PLACES API",
        placeType: .Address
    )
```

I am not able to figure out how to get this `viewcontroller` functionality work on my `uitextfield` so it can work exactly as it works on `uitextfield`

Comment: did you done this with textfield in swift? if so, I am also looking for same, can you provide sample if possible, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why do not use Google Places API for iOS ? It has all the capability as seen on the mentioned library. Here is the link https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

and you can use the fetcher object to get the predictions and according to whatever requirement you can customize the result. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

**Google autocomplete API using search bar**

**1)**

```
let googleAutoCompeteApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&types=establishment|geocode&location=%@,%@&radius=500&language=en&key=%@"
var arrPlaces = NSMutableArray(capacity: 100)
let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
let googleServerkey = "Your API KEY"
```

**2)**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.beginSearching(searchText: searchText)
}

func beginSearching(searchText:String) {
    if searchText.count == 0 {
        self.arrPlaces.removeAllObjects()
        // self.tblOfflineCity.reloadData()
        return
    }

    operationQueue.addOperation { () -> Void in
        self.forwardGeoCoding(searchTexts:searchText)
    }
}

//MARK: - Search place from Google -


func forwardGeoCoding(searchTexts:String) {
    googlePlacesResult(input: searchTexts) { (result) -> Void in
        let searchResult:NSDictionary = ["keyword":searchTexts,"results":result]
        if result.count > 0
        {
            let features = searchResult.value(forKey: "results") as! [AnyObject]
            self.arrPlaces = NSMutableArray(capacity: 100)

            for dictAddress in features   {
                if let content = dictAddress.value(forKey:"description") as? String {
                    self.arrPlaces.addObjects(from: [content])
                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //self.tblOfflineCity.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func googlePlacesResult(input: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: NSArray) -> Void) {
    let searchWordProtection = input.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    if searchWordProtection.count != 0 {
        let urlString = NSString(format: googleAutoCompeteApi as NSString,input,currentLat,currentLong,googleServerkey)
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        let defaultConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let delegateFreeSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
        let task =  delegateFreeSession.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest,completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let jSONresult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                    let results:NSArray = jSONresult["predictions"] as! NSArray
                    let status = jSONresult["status"] as! String

                    if status == "NOT_FOUND" || status == "REQUEST_DENIED" {
                        let userInfo:NSDictionary = ["error": jSONresult["status"]!]

                        let newError = NSError(domain: "API Error", code: 666, userInfo: userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject] as [NSObject : AnyObject] as? [String : Any])
                        let arr:NSArray = [newError]
                        completion(arr)
                        return
                    } else {
                        completion(results)
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print("json error: \(error)")
                }
            } else if error != nil {
                // print(error.description)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

**you will get result in self.arrPlaces. To use in uitextField only you need to call function using uitextField delegate instead of searchbar**

Comment: Where is table view delegate methods, bro?

Comment: When I select one place means what happened next, Can you give table view delegate for did select row bro?

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       print(arrPlaces.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)
    }                                                                                                                      you need to use **arrPlaces** array to display data in tableview

Comment: How can i get the lat long for each result?

Comment: You need to implement above code with some correction related to API key and other parameters, And print the output of googlePlacesResult. You will get lat long in that.